# How do I open a webpage after tapping image when using binding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making an atom reader for Windows Phone. The mainpage.xaml.cs code looks like this:

```
void ywc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(e.Result);
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
    var document = XDocument.Load(reader);

    XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
    var YTitems = from entry in document.Descendants(atom + "entry")
                  select new RSSFeed
                  {
                       ImageSRC = entry.Element(media + "group").Element(media + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
                       Title = entry.Element(atom + "title").Value,
                       pubDate = entry.Element(atom + "published").Value.Substring(0, 10),
                       VideoURL  = entry.Element(media + "group").Element(media + "content").Attribute("url").Value                                    
                   };
    YoutubeList.ItemsSource = YTitems.ToList();                
}

private void screenshot_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("insertyoutubeurihere");

    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = uri;
    webBrowserTask.Show();            
}
```

The mainpage.xaml code looks like this:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,0" Name="YoutubeList">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Width="Auto">
                <Image x:Name="screenshot" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSRC}" Width="150" Tap="screenshot_Tap"/>
                <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=pubDate}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

I don't really know how I can link the uri to the corresponding VideoURL.
So when he user taps, than it opens the webpage with the url of the video.

Comment: do you know how to extract the video url from the "tap" event or just how to launch the web browser?

Comment: I have extracted the url as a string. But I can't figure out how to launch it

Comment: Just use this: System.Diagnostics.Process.Star t(urlString); ... this should launch the url in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Command binding. Instead of two textblocks you can use a button or Hyperlink. Bind the Command property of the button or hyperlink to an ICommand property of your viewmodel.

More information about ICommand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.icommand

In case you are using MVVM Light, you could also take a look at the RelayCommand class.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
<StackPanel>
       <HyperlinkButton Height="310" 
                        Width="200" 
                        NavigateUri="{Binding Path=ImageSRC}" 
                        Name="hyperlinkButton1" 
                        TargetName="_blank"> 
            <HyperlinkButton.Background> 
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=ImageSRC}"/> 
            </HyperlinkButton.Background> 
        </HyperlinkButton>

...

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(urlString);
```

...

this should launch the url in the default browser, no matter what platform you're on (WinXP, WinVista, Win7, Win8, etc)...

keep in mind that it expects a full url to recognize it as that and launch the browser...